# Calculate the mean of a list with counts for each value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List<ChickenByWeight>` I'm struggling to find a way to calculate the average weight for all the chickens

```
class ChickenByWeight extends Equatable {
  final int count;
  final int weight;

  ChickenByWeight({
    required this.weight,
    required this.count,
  });

  ChickenByWeight copyWith({
    int? count,
    int? weight,
  }) {
    return ChickenByWeight(
      count: count ?? this.count,
      weight: weight ?? this.weight,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        count,
        weight,
      ];
}
```

I'd like to return the result with this method :

```
double averageChickenWeight(List<ChickenByWeight> chickenByWeight) {
  
  return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I believe the code below is what you need. I omitted Equatable since it seems to not have any influence here.

```
class ChickenByWeight { 
  final int count;
  final int weight;

  ChickenByWeight({
    required this.weight,
    required this.count,
  });

  ChickenByWeight copyWith({
    int? count,
    int? weight,
  }) {
    return ChickenByWeight(
      count: count ?? this.count,
      weight: weight ?? this.weight,
    );
  }
}

double averageChickenWeight(List<ChickenByWeight> chickenByWeight) {
  var sum = 0.0;
  var count = 0.0;
  for(final chicken in chickenByWeight){
    sum += chicken.weight * chicken.count;
    count += chicken.count;
  }
  return sum / count;
}

void main() {
  var chickenList = <ChickenByWeight>[];
  final chicken1 = ChickenByWeight(weight:3,count: 1);
  final chicken2 = ChickenByWeight(weight:5,count: 2);
  chickenList.add(chicken1);
  chickenList.add(chicken2);
  
  print(averageChickenWeight(chickenList));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class User {
  int age;
  String name;
  
  User(this.age, this.name);
}
void main() {
  List<User> list = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    User user = User(i, "Name $i");
    list.add(user);
  }
  
  double avg = list.map((e) => e.age).average;
  print(avg); 
}
```

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for -> as you can see each `ChickenByWeight` has a `chickenCount` that I need to take into account when calculating the `mean` but thanks for trying ! : ) - @Wiktor answer solves my question

Comment: True, you need to modify the `=> e.age` part where you put your multiplication, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
double averageChickenWeight(List<ChickenByWeight> chickenByWeight) {
  return chickenByWeight.map((m) => m.weight).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / chickenByWeight.length;
  
}
```

for this sample:

```
List<ChickenByWeight> sample = [ ChickenByWeight(weight:1,count:1), ChickenByWeight(weight:2,count:2)];
  print(averageChickenWeight(sample));
```

the output would be `1.5`